# How do I peel prosciutto from wax paper without it coming off in strips?

Tags: ham, salami

Anytime I've purchased prosciutto from a store it's sold in slices separated by pieces of wax paper, but when I try and peel it off it doesn't peel evenly. The lines of fat in the ham offers less strength when peeling, and the prosciutto often tears along these lines.

When trying to make sandwiches it isn't too much of an aesthetic issue, but if I'm trying to make a charcuterie board having thin strips isn't as appealing. Is there some best way to scrape the meat from the wax paper, peel from both ends simultaneously? Or is this an inconvenience I'll just have to deal with?

Comment: Flip it over and get off the wax paper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually use a palette knife (frosting spatula) to separate the slice from the paper by sliding it betwixt the two.  It is quick, but does require some care.

Comment: ...and make sure it is cold...

Comment: @moscafj Good point; nearly molten fat is a pain.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds easier to flip the wax-paper prosciutto and carefully peel the wax paper off, just make sure that the meat gets a grip on the surface of which you place it on.

Another way is that you can try placing it in freezer for just a while until the prosciutto stiffens up a bit, and then attempt to peel the paper off the prosciutto, as the paper won't get stiff.

My last suggestion is to place the wax paper on a damp warm/hot towel for a minute.